# how to call doSave(IProgressMonitor) function of FormEditor in SWT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

In an Eclipse plugin project, I have an editor which extends `FormEditor`. The user can save the editor when press Ctrl+S. I have created a save button in the editor, so I want to save the editor when I press the save button. I call the `doSave(IProgressMonitor)` function of editor, but I can't find the default object of `IProgressMonitor`. I can't provider the parameter:  IProgressMonitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to save an editor is to call the `IWorkbenchPage` `saveEditor` method, this will call the editor `doSave` with the correct progress monitor:

Use something like:

```java
IEditorPart editorPart = ... your editor ...

IWorkbenchPage page = editorPart.getSite().getPage();

page.saveEditor(editorPart, false);
```